S360 issue - Disable local auth for non-prod Storage Accounts
I have EV2 script with type : Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
  "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
  "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
  "name": "[variables('waitTimeForDSSettingsName')]",
  "location": "[variables('defaultLocation')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[extensionResourceId(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityPerimeters', variables('nspResourceName')), 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings', parameters('dsSettingName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('waitTimeForDSSettingsTag')]",
    "azPowerShellVersion": "3.0",
    "scriptContent": "start-sleep -Seconds 120",
    "cleanupPreference": "Always",
    "retentionInterval": "PT1H"
  }
}

This creates storage accounts which can not have allowSharedKeyAccess to be False. Even if we use existing storage, the Shared access key can not be disabled. Documentation here.
The S360 guidance clearly mentions that:
All Microsoft-owned Storage Accounts MUST:

Use Identity-Based access control with Managed Identity.
Disable Shared Key access. Link here

What exception could be raised for this issue?

Can you explain bit more? You need to Disable Shared Key authorization with existing storage accounts?

If yes can you try with azure cli commands?


This creates storage accounts which can not have allowSharedKeyAccess to be False. Even if we use existing storage, the Shared access key can not be disabled. Documentation here.

As you said, The deployment script you're using sets up resources that need Azure Storage Accounts with Shared Key access enabled. This goes against the S360 guidelines that require Shared Key access to be turned off.
You can be manually able to disable the shared key access the existing storage account by using this MS-Document (PowerShell, Cli and Templates)
Command:
az storage account update \ 
  --name  <storage-account> \ 
  --resource-group  <resource-group> \ 
  --allow-shared-key-access  false

Output:
venkatesan [ ~ ]$ az storage account update --name venkatzzz123 --resource-group venkzzz-rg --allow-shared-key-access false
{
  "accessTier": "Hot",
  "accountMigrationInProgress": null,
  "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
  "allowCrossTenantReplication": false,
  "allowSharedKeyAccess": false,
  "allowedCopyScope": null,
  "azureFilesIdentityBasedAuthentication": null,
  "blobRestoreStatus": null,
  "creationTime": "2024-07-11T06:19:00.608375+00:00",
  "customDomain": null,
  "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": false,
  "dnsEndpointType": "Standard",
  "enableExtendedGroups": null,
  "enableHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
  "enableNfsV3": null,
  "encryption": {
    "encryptionIdentity": null,
    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",
    "keyVaultProperties": null,
    "requireInfrastructureEncryption": false,
    "services": {
      "blob": {
        "enabled": true,
        "keyType": "Account",
        "lastEnabledTime": "2024-07-11T06:19:00.748996+00:00"
      },
      "file": {
        "enabled": true,
        "keyType": "Account",
        "lastEnabledTime": "2024-07-11T06:19:00.748996+00:00"
      },
      "queue": null,
      "table": null
    }
  },
  "extendedLocation": null,
  "failoverInProgress": null,
  "geoReplicationStats": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/b8287d24-6b90-4f69-a971-e7c0e43fec67/resourceGroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat326123",
  "identity": null,
  "immutableStorageWithVersioning": null,
  "isHnsEnabled": null,
  "isLocalUserEnabled": null,
  "isSftpEnabled": null,
  "isSkuConversionBlocked": null,
  "keyCreationTime": {
    "key1": "2024-07-11T06:19:00.748996+00:00",
    "key2": "2024-07-11T06:19:00.748996+00:00"
  },
  "keyPolicy": null,
  "kind": "StorageV2",
  "largeFileSharesState": "Enabled",
  "lastGeoFailoverTime": null,
  "location": "eastus",
  "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
  "name": "venkat326123",
  "networkRuleSet": {
    "bypass": "AzureServices",
    "defaultAction": "Allow",
    "ipRules": [],
    "ipv6Rules": [],
    "resourceAccessRules": null,
    "virtualNetworkRules": []
  },
  "primaryEndpoints": {
    "blob": "https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "dfs": "https://venkat326123.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    "file": "https://venkat326123.file.core.windows.net/",
    "internetEndpoints": null,
    "microsoftEndpoints": null,
    "queue": "https://venkat326123.queue.core.windows.net/",
    "table": "https://venkat326123.table.core.windows.net/",
    "web": "https://venkat326123.z13.web.core.windows.net/"
  },
  "primaryLocation": "eastus",
  "privateEndpointConnections": [],
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
  "resourceGroup": "venkatesan-rg",
  "routingPreference": null,
  "sasPolicy": null,
  "secondaryEndpoints": {
    "blob": "https://venkat326123-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "dfs": "https://venkat326123-secondary.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    "file": null,
    "internetEndpoints": null,
    "microsoftEndpoints": null,
    "queue": "https://venkat326123-secondary.queue.core.windows.net/",
    "table": "https://venkat326123-secondary.table.core.windows.net/",
    "web": "https://venkat326123-secondary.z13.web.core.windows.net/"
  },
  "secondaryLocation": "westus",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "statusOfPrimary": "available",
  "statusOfSecondary": "available",
  "storageAccountSkuConversionStatus": null,
  "tags": {},
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
}


You can verify in the portal.

After disabling shared key access, you can be able to authenticate with managed identity authentication.
